# using WHERE clause as a variable in MySQL query not working

Tags: php, mysql

This is really weird.

This query obviously works:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM restaurant_page WHERE title LIKE '%$search_title%'");
```

But, this doesn't:

```
$category = 'restaurant_page';

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM '$category' WHERE title LIKE '%$search_title%'");
```

With the second query, I get the resource boolean error.

`$category` is table the user wants to search from.  When I print out the query with the variable, it's the exact same as the first one.  Why wouldn't this work?

Comment: I hightly doubt "it's the exact same as the first one".

Comment: Make sure you sanitize your input. http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Got is guys.  Thanks.  It was ticks.  I was thinking INSERT VALUES.  Uggg... That was dumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use single quotes around your table name, use backticks (`` ` ``) instead:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `$category` WHERE title LIKE '%$search_title%'");
```

NB. Please make sure that `$category` and `$search_title` are not plain user provided variables

Answer (score 2):

Does the query created with the variable have quotes areound the table name?  That seems like a mistake to me.

Answer (score 1):

in the mysql query, don't put quotes around $category.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $category WHERE title LIKE '%$search_title%'");
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the single quotes from `'$category'`.

```
"SELECT * FROM '$category' WHERE title LIKE '%$search_title%'"
---------------^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If needed, surround `$category` with backticks. This is only necessary if `$category` contains a MySQL reserved keyword. However, since it is a variable that could become a possiblity.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `$category` WHERE title LIKE '%$search_title%'");
```

Of course, please don't forget to escape `$category` since it may be user input. We assume you have already done so for `$search_title` as well.

```
$category = mysql_real_escape_string($category);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why have you got quotes around $category  - remove these and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should always seperate the variables from the actual string. Do something like this:

```
$category = "restaurant_page";

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `".$category."` WHERE title LIKE
'%".$search_title."%'");
```

Answer (score 0):

LOL. This makes my day. 
remove the quote on the $category. Im sure this is just a funny mistake. All of us made some mistake. hehe

To solve this change the ' to "

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$category." WHERE title LIKE '%$search_title%'");
```