# Using a variable in a PHP MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to user a variable inside of a PHP MySQL query to represent the WHERE clause like so:

```
$where= name=mark AND address=4;

$query= "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE $where";
```

Am I doing this correct? If not, what is the correct what to do so?

Comment: Consider revising [basic variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php).

Comment: [Duplicated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157371/using-where-clause-as-a-variable-in-mysql-query-not-working),

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP method is correct, however you need single quotes around the string in SQL and also you need to wrap your string php variable with quotes, so your variable should look like this:

```
$where = "name = 'mark' AND address = 4";
$query = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE {$where}";
```

Comment: You need to use parameterized queries for proper escaping and security! Consider PDO or mysqli instead of concatenating variables like this.

Comment: Thanks, I use PDO myself, just answering the OP's question

Comment: @user113215 You do not know yet from where the variables are coming. It can be perfectly safe too.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want :

```
$where = "name= 'mark' AND address= '4'";

$query= "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE $where";
```

Put double quotes around value of $where. Also the value of MySQL table field should be wrapped in quotes

Comment: You need to use parameterized queries for proper escaping and security! Consider PDO or mysqli instead of concatenating variables like this.

Comment: I posted the answer to OP's question.

Comment: @user113215 is very quick with the downvote trigger. +1 to make up for it.

Comment: Avoiding SQL injection is a necessary part of the answer to "Am I doing this correct?".

Comment: @user113215 He is using static variables for the query here. So what's the issue with security ? The values are not dynamically coming. So this method is safe and correct for his question.

Comment: If it were really a static string it wouldn't need a variable... The question has been simplified.

Comment: @user113215 **If it were really a static string it wouldn't need a variable...** Why not?

Comment: @user113215 Assuming is just about the worst thing you can do in programming.

Comment: All I'm saying is that any acceptable answer must at least _address_ SQL injection. Even if you don't give a detailed explanation or a working example, you do need to mention it.

Answer (score 0):

Your practice of handling php variables inside quotes is wrong .. and your syntax is also wrong .
whenever you want to use php variable in side double quotes ..you should include it in square brackets `{}`.
And since you are using `$where` as string it should be properly enclosed within strings

```
$where= "name='mark' AND address=4";

$query= "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE {$where}";
```

Though this may not be relevant here but another good practise is to use [sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) while using the php variables with strings

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE %s", $where);
```